# How to get all posts where author leaved a comment?

Tags: php, activerecord, yii

How to get all the posts where current user made a comment. I have a relationships between tables, but the situation is difficult to me. It should be something like this:

```
$posts = Yii::app()->user->comments->posts->findAll(); // don't think that is my code, it just for explanation of query chain
```

so I need to get all posts where user leaved a comment.

In the sql my query works fine:

```
SELECT tc.title, tc.content, t.post_id
FROM tbl_comment t
JOIN tbl_post tc
ON t.post_id =tc.id
WHERE author_id =43
GROUP BY t.post_id

$CD = new CDbCriteria;
$CD->condition = 'tc.author_id='.Yii::app()->user->id;
$CD->join = 'JOIN tbl_comment tc ON t.id=tc.post_id';
$posts = Post::model()->findAll($CD);
```

This is it.

Comment: You realize the example SQL you posted is very different, in that it's using a WHERE clause to filter instead of an IN clause . . . do you want PHP for that SQL, or what your first example shows?

Comment: I know, it because I'm trying to find the optimal solution, without `IN`.

Comment: If that's the case, it sounds like you should make sure your model includes the author_id, and if you know the author_id, writing the critiera using `addColumnCondition(array('author_id'=>$value))` or something similar . . .

Comment: my comment model and post has authors (id).

Comment: Okay, so what have you tried?  Do you have a model?  Have you created criteria?  Have you applied criteria?

Comment: yes, and seems it even works, wait a lit bit.

Comment: though better to add also `$CD->group = 'tc.post_id';`

Comment: @AviAtion Why did you accept an answer and then change the question completely so that it doesn't match the answer anymore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than defining your IN clause manually, you can use [addInCondition()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#addInCondition-detail), i.e.:

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->addInCondition('id', $postIds)
$posts=Post::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

You can view the source from the Yii documentation page, and you'll see that the code there splits up the parameters and then joins them, similiar to what @Wilq is suggesting.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a string for that parameter just do an `implode()` on your array.

Try:

```
$criteria->params = array(':id' => implode(',',$postIds));
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading your code makes me think $postIds is an array of IDs. Is that right ?
If so, you can't assign $postIds to the :id query parameter, you need to do several queries whith a single posted id each time.

Comment: `$postIds is an array of IDs` yes!